# Resetting rich text area in lwc record edit form

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have a lwc

with the following code in html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={object} onsuccess={handleRecordCreate}>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
          <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-input-field field-name={emailField}></lightning-input-field>                
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-input-field field-name={subjectField}></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_2-of-2">
                <lightning-input-rich-text field-name={descriptionField}></lightning-input-rich-text>
            </div>
          </div>
        <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" label="Create Freshdesk Ticket"></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button  label="Cancel" onclick={allowReset}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

From the cancel button I am calling allowReset where I would like to reset both the input-fields as well as the rich text area. The issue here is that the input fields are getting reset but not the rich text area.

```js
  allowReset() {
             [...this.template
         .querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field, lightning-input-rich-text')]
         .forEach((input) => { input.reset(); });*/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lightning-input-rich-text` doesn't have a `reset()` function instead you have to use the `setRangeText()` instead.

```js
resetRichTextFields() {
  this.template
    .querySelectorAll("lightning-input-rich-text")
    .forEach((input) => {
      input.setRangeText("", 0, input.value.length, "start");
    });
}
```

```js
allowReset() {
  ...
  this.resetRichTextFields();
}
```

You can see the different methods available for `lightning-input-rich-text` here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/specification